# Why do I feel Newton's first law is wrong?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Before 2 days I asked a question on energy conversation of collision , got an answer........ but see this problem. There is such interesting in this question.

2kg object is moving on a floor without friction with 6ms-1 velocity while the 4kg object is on rest(no velocity. They collide each other and when the collision occurs,  whole kinetic energy transfer into sound energy.( full kinetic energy transfer into sound energy).

After the collision there is no kinetic energy in the system. So the two objects should be in rest after the collision. Now see this...

There is no any external force affected to the system. Only an interial force while the collision. So the momentum should be constant according to newton's first law. But see the initial and final momentum of the system. Momentum is different.

Initial-12Kgms-1

Final-0kgms-1

Why the momentum values have different values while the system hasn't any external force. They should be constant.

I don't know what is the  case. Is there problem in my thinking or Newton' first law???

(Edit: or is it that the Newton's first law is correct but you can never make a situation with no external force ?)

Comment: If you want to consider a medium in which sound propagates, you cannot just say that it exist whenever you want to. If there is a medium in which sound can propagate it also must exist before the impact, not only from the moment the impact takes place later on. If you consider this, you should notice that momentum is transferred from the moving body to the  medium in which it propagates even before the collision, so your system is not made only of 2 bodies anymore. You have to consider the medium in this.

Comment: Are you saying that one object is colliding with a stationary object, and after the collision they are both stationary? With nothing such as friction to stop them?  That is an impossible situation. Would you mind making a sketch of this situation?

Comment: Re *They collide each other and when the collision occurs, whole kinetic energy transfer into sound energy. ... After the collision there is no kinetic energy in the system* -- That can't happen. You are making up your own laws of physics that are contrary to what is observed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have described an impossible scenario.

No external forces means that momentum is conserved and that law gives you the sum of final momentum of the bodies as equal to the sum of the initial momentum of the bodies.

In your example there is a net momentum after the collision and so the final kinetic energy of the bodies **cannot** be zero.

---

On another point.
As a result of an inelastic collision when the kinetic energy becomes less the colliding bodies are permanently deformed (bonds between molecules are broken) and they also become hotter.  Sound is also produced but that contributes very little to the loss in kinetic energy of the bodies.